# How to open division in another html page which is hidden using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are two html files in same folder. 
file1.html
file2.html
The problem is to open specific division in file2 which is hidden by clicking a class in file 1.

There is a class "back" in file1 and division with id "content-3" in file2. I am trying to write a function which will un-hide the division "content-3" in file2 when one clicks on class "back" in file1.

```
$('body').on('click', '.back', function() {      

  window.location.href = "file2.html";

 $('#content-3').show();


});
```

It opens file2. But it doesn't show the division in file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is each page has it's own window and javascript in first page is gone when second page opens

You could add a hash to the url and inside second page check for that hash

```
$('body').on('click', '.back', function() {
  window.location.href = "file2.html#content-3";
});
```

In other page:

```
$(function(){
   var hash = location.hash
   if(hash && hash !=='#'){
     $(hash).show()
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the href of a site and a new page loads, the JavaScript that is running will be stopped. This means that `$('#content-3').show();` does not get executed. Instead you might want to provide the value that you want to display through the url or querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the show code from the click event.

Separately add this conditional logic:

```
if(window.location.href === yourpage.com) { $('#content-3').show() }
```

Make sure your other page has access to your Javascript file.

Comment: If it was that straightforward why ever hide it?

Comment: Lmao, oh God. I can tell it's Sunday. The logic on this one definitely went over my head.